# The problem with Wordpress Importer

Tags: plugins, posts, theme-development, themes, xml

I've tried many times to upload theme-unit-test-data.xml from http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test
But when I'm trying to upload this file in WordPress Importer it gives me an error saying:

> Sorry, there has been an error. This does not appear to be a WXR file,
>   missing/invalid WXR version number

I'm using the latest version (4.0) of the WordPress CMS.

**Edit:** I reinstalled the WordPress importer plugin and downloaded the Theme Unit test XML file multiple times with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your XML file not valid. Try to import another xml and check. If another xml imports then its 100% issue with your XML in which you are getting error.

Comment: I've tried several others, it didn't help much.

Comment: Did you specified WXR version in your file? Like :<wp:wxr_version>1.1</wp:wxr_version>

Comment: Yes, it was specified in the origital file: <wp:wxr_version>1.2</wp:wxr_version>

Comment: change permission of your wp-content to 755. Then try. This is last try I think.

Comment: Also try by changing browser , clear cache of your wordpress site using cache plugin.then try to import.

Comment: Changing permissions on directory has solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
It turned out that there were some [ASCII - control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) in the file (export.xml) which are not accepted by the importer. Some of those characters are only visible in a hex-editor.

I removed those characters with the following terminal command:

```
tr -d '\000-\010\013\014\016-\037\177' < export.xml > new-export.xml
```

The [tr command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) shown above removes all control characters except *Horizontal Tab*, *Line Feed* and *Carriage Return* from the file and saves a clean file. The new-export.xml then was successfully accepted by the importer.